# Trouble adding values in combobox column of datagridview c#

Tags: c#, datagridview, datagridviewcolumn

I have a datagridview, in this datagirdview, i added two unbound columns, one is a combobox and second is a textbox type column, besides this , I have a datatable of some rows.

I am setting gird datasource with my datatable, then I am trying to add values to combobox control, it should display three values (Truck, Plane, Ship)

when grid loads it displays stores, but no value in combobox, I tried various methods like creating a combobox data column and adding values to it by binding a datatable, I also tried by adding in column.items both in designer and by code but combobox never gets the values.

as an experiment I am also trying to add a new column by below code, but second column also show no values.

```
DataGridViewComboBoxColumn dgvcbc = new DataGridViewComboBoxColumn();
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        dt.Columns.Add("Media", typeof(string));
        dt.Rows.Add("Truck");
        dt.Rows.Add("Car");
        dgvcbc.DataSource = dt;
        dgvcbc.DisplayMember = "Media";
        dgvcbc.ValueMember = "Media";
        this.grdDestShops.Columns.Add(dgvcbc);
```

Comment: try to remove `dgvcbc.ValueMember = "Media";`

Comment: I did that but no results.

Comment: i tried your code above and its fine.. where did you placed your codes?

Answer (score 0):

your code is adding a new column!, If you have added a ComboBox columns in the design mode, why not you find it using `FindControl` function and then bound it?

Comment: I know I am adding a new column, but even the newly added column is not showing values....

Comment: Are you using the `itemdatabound` event

Answer (score 0):

Think this solves ur problem..

```
namespace activator
{
    public partial class Form2 : Form
    {
        public Form2()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
       {
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        dt.Columns.Add("Media", typeof(string));
        dt.Rows.Add("Truck");
        dt.Rows.Add("Car");            
        ComboBox combo = new ComboBox();
        List<string> media=(from x in dt.AsEnumerable()
                            select x.Field<string>(0)).ToList();
        combo.DataSource = media;
        dataGridView1.Controls.Add(combo);           
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: you cannot set datatable as a datasource for combobox..bt u can set list as source..

Comment: He can set a `DataTable` as a `DataSource`

Comment: i did it for a single combo box..if it is a DataGridViewComboBoxColumn he can iterate the same for each datarow..